# Integal of ds ==> Integal Integal of r dθ dr

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

From Page 177 of differential equations demystified (2005):

We must evaluate the integral I: (1)

$$ I = \int_{\infty}^{0} e^{- s^{2}} $$

observe that: (2)

$$I \cdot I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- s^{2}}\, ds \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- u^{2}}\, du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} e^{- r^{2}} r d\theta dr $$

Could somebody explain these steps in better detail.  I'm not really sure how they get from (1) to the double integral in polar coordinates in (2)

Comment: I suggest making the title more clear and informative.

Comment: any suggestions for a title?

Answer (score 2):

Note that  $$I = \int_{\infty}^{0} e^{- s^{2}} =  \int_{\infty}^{0} e^{- u^{2}}$$ because 
$s$ is a dummy variable so we can as well denote it by $u$

Multiply the two integrals to get $$I \cdot I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- s^{2}}\, ds \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- u^{2}}\, du=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{- u^{2}-s^2}dsdu $$

Use polar coordinates with the region of integration being the first quadrant.

Note that in polar coordinates  element of the area is $rdrd\theta$ instead of $dsdu$

Note that $$r^2 = s^2 + u^2$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} e^{- r^{2}} r d\theta dr$$

Comment: Great. :) I'll remove the comment now. :)

Comment: You might want to show how ${\rm d}s {\rm d}u = r {\rm d}r {\rm d}\theta$ given $(u=r\cos\theta, s = r \sin \theta)$.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks for the comment. I added a note to my answer.